# Mixed Static and dynamic content site using AWS S3 and EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, mod-rewrite, java, amazon-s3

We are installing a Java web application in a EC2 running Tomcat.
The application uses a folder for users pictures (static content)-> www.example.com/PICTURES

We use mod_jk to exclude Tomcat from serving the path /PICTURES so it is Apache who serve it.

We are planning to move /PICTURES to S3 and serve them from our bucket.

In our code we use short urls,so for example, a user picture is defined as: /PICTURES/1.jpg

We want to redirect every call from *www.example.com/PICTURES/** to our bucket -> *example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/PICTURES*

We have been searching for the best strategy but it seems the are not an unified solution.

As far I know we should use:

a) mod_rewrite: creating regex for every static content we would like to redirect to ur bucket

b) proxy: work as a proxy to S3

Is there any other solution? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camilo create or edit your .htaccess file and add the lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/PROFILES/(.+) http://pictures.example.com/PROFILES/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use a different domain for static content (e.g. `static.example.com`) which points to S3 or CloudFront. Proxying to S3 isn't going to buy you anything, and redirecting is going to add extra latency to every request.

Comment: Great answer. As a bonus, you may be able to serve static.example.com as a cookieless subdomain, if you're careful.

Comment: Thanks @mgorven! I got it, and we have prepared a cname in our DNS to redirect to `static.example.com`. The problem is: how can we achieve this in our code? Right now we do something like this: `user.getPicture` and that return `/pictures/user.jpg` and therefore the server insert this code in the html: `http://example.com/pictures/user.jpg` but what we really want is: `http://static.example.com/pictures/user.jpg`  How can we do it?

Comment: @CamiloLopez-DeFelipe You'll need to change your application to support that.